# Spring MVC controller not returning values

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc. I am trying to get a response back from the model view controller on my helloworld.jsp. when I run the application I only get ${message} ${name} defined on the page.  I used sysout in the controller file but not getting anything on the console as well. please can you check what I am missing?

spring-mvc version: 4.2.6.RELEASE

**index.jsp**

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring 4 MVC - HelloWorld Index Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <center>
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
                <h3>
                    <a href="helloworld.jsp">Click Here</a>
                </h3>
            </center>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**helloworld.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 4 MVC -HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>${message} ${name}</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.testcontroller" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

**TestController.java**

```
package com.test.testcontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView showMessage() {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
        mv.addObject("message", "this is a message for");
        mv.addObject("name", "Spring");
        return mv;
    }

}
```

Application structure

[image]

**Log:**

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher'
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization started
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:23 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jun 13 09:30:23 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:24 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jun 13 09:30:23 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:24 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jun 13 09:30:23 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:24 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization completed in 1211 ms
Jun 13, 2016 9:30:24 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestApp/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

Comment: your link should be `/index` not to the jsp. also if yu can use the link you have in your `index.jsp` your jsp isn't where you tell spring it is.

Comment: Deinum, sorry, i didn't get that. please can you advise what/where I should change?

Comment: What I said. Change the link in your file to `/index`...

Comment: which file? helloworld.jsp, index.jsp??

Comment: Do you have a link in `hello world.jsp`?

Comment: no, I don't :).  I've changed the link as <a href="/index">Click Here</a> but its now throwing resource not found.

Comment: Is it reaching the controller?

Comment: don't think as I can't see system out message in the console

Comment: The link should actually be `/<context-root>/index` if your application isn't the root application .

Comment: I've put /webapp/index in the link but still no luck. why you calling /index from index.jsp by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some issues with creating spring mvc project using maven. For Some reasons, it does not generate .class files. I tried various options but none worked for me.

Then I created a simple Dynamic web project and its working fine.

I still want to know why maven did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the updated index.jsp. Also we are giving link as index as your request mapping is /index only.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring 4 MVC - HelloWorld Index Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <center>
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
                <h3>
                    <a href="index">Click Here</a>
                </h3>
            </center>
        </body>
        </html>
```

check for this line in the tomcat console logs

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/index]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.test.testcontroller.TestController.showMessage()
```

If it is not there it means request mapping is not done. Refer below updated web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

After doing all this you will get

```
HTTP Status 404 - /spring-mvc-check/WEB-INF/helloworld.jsp
```

To resolve this put helloworld.jsp inside WEB-INF.

Updated with pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-check</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api-2.0</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: getting this error----------------Jun 10, 2016 4:08:16 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestApp/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Comment: Can you paste your application startup log ? You had already tried with /index and now you tried with /TestApp/index also. Did you see /index mapping in the startup?

Comment: I was talking about this log  `INFO: Mapped "{[/index]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.test.testcontroller.TestController.showMessage()` Now your jsp helloworld is not in WEB-INF and mapping in viewResolver is for WEB-INF. So you should get something like `HTTP Status 404 - /TestApp/WEB-INF/helloworld.jsp`  Put it in WEB-INF and it should solve the problem.

Comment: I am not getting that entry in the Log file. I've changed the web.xml as you have suggested but still no luck

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are missing here. I have updated the answer with pom.xml also. Please copy that and try. I guess that is the only file remaining now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to web.xml under spring-dispatcher servlet

```
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Comment: I've tried adding this tag but getting error ----cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'

Comment: Can you post your whole web.xml and servlet.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You use to settings default Spring(sts) and not problem in settings

First, You don`t using index.jsp.
Just use helloworld.jsp.

(Controller)

```
package com.test.testcontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/show/message")
    public ModelAndView showMessage(ModelAndView mv) {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        mv.addObject("message", "this is a message for");
        mv.addObject("name", "Spring");
        mv.setViewName("/helloworld");

        return mv;
    }

}
```

input in Browser a url(you localhost/context path/show/message).
you success to show message.

if you want to using index.jsp
(you index.jsp)

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Spring 4 MVC - HelloWorld Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <center>
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <h3>
                <a href="/show/message">Click Here</a>
            </h3>
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You add code in controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String showIndex() {

        return "/index";
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

by default EL is disabled.

add

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

to jsp enable it.